# SignalR invoke not returning when used in an async method

Tags: c#, signalr, async-await, signalr.client

I'm not sure if this is a SignalR issue or an async/await issue. When my client app (WPF) starts up, it does some initialisation:-

```
public async void Initialise()
{
    // Get data from the server - async, as it may be long-running.
    var data = await _hubProxy.Invoke<FooData>("Method1");

    _dataProcessor.ProcessData(data);
}
```

The `_dataProcessor` is a helper class that does some stuff with the data passed to it, then at some point calls a different server method using a line similar to:-

```
var moreData = _hubProxy.Invoke<BarData>("Method2").Result;
```

None of the code in the helper class is async.

The first server invoke (in `Initialise()`) works fine - it gets back the data and passes it to the helper class. This proceeds without issue until *its* `invoke` - it gets called but never returns, and the thread never proceeds past this line. I've put a breakpoint in the server method and can confirm that it is being called and returning a value, but for some reason this is not getting back to the client.

The strange thing is, if I take out the async/await keywords in the `Initialise()` method, everything works fine. What am I doing wrong? Why would these keywords affect the synchronous code in the helper class?

(I realise you shouldn't normally use `async void`, but as the Initialise() method is "fire and forget", I thought it was okay in this scenario).

Comment: I don't think `Initialize` is "fire and forget". That would literally mean that the rest of your code doesn't care whether (or if) that object was initialized. You may find my blog post on [`async` constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) helpful.

Comment: Seconded: you should use `async Task` instead of `async void`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line causes a deadlock on the UI thread:

```
var moreData = _hubProxy.Invoke<BarData>("Method2").Result;
```

Make `ProcessData` an `async` method and await `_hubProxy.Invoke` inside it:

```
var moreData = await _hubProxy.Invoke<BarData>("Method2");
```

Then, await `_dataProcessor.ProcessData` in your `Initialise`:

```
await _dataProcessor.ProcessData(data);
```

Make sure you don't use `.Result` or `.Wait` anywhere else.

Another way of solving it is just this:

```
public async void Initialise()
{
    // Get data from the server - async, as it may be long-running.
    var data = await _hubProxy.Invoke<FooData>("Method1").ConfigureAwait(false);

    _dataProcessor.ProcessData(data);
}
```

Note `ConfigureAwait(false)`. In this case the continuation after `await` will happen on a non-UI thread. This will eliminate the deadlock, but this is not an ideal solution, rather a workaround. Moreover, your logic may require the continuation on the UI thread, for UI access or some thread-safety concerns.

The best solution would be to use both `ConfigureAwait(false)` (if possible) and avoid blocking with `.Result` or `.Wait`, at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not familiar with ConfigureAwait(), but this article goes some way to providing an explanation of the problem: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html.

Comment: When I debug the thread IDs, it shows that the UI thread is calling `Initialise()` (as expected), but a different thread is executing the helper code after the await (again expected, kind of. I guess the async framework fires up a new thread to continue execution after the `await`). But I'm still not clear on why there would be a deadlock between the two different threads? Or is it to do with contexts, rather than threads, as the above article describes?

Comment: @AndrewStephens, this is unexpected. If you call `Initialise` on the WPF UI thread, and don't call `ConfigureAwait(false)` anywhere, there should be no thread after `await`. The framework doesn't magically spin off new threads. Are you sure it's a different thread? Do you use `Task.Run` anywhere?

Comment: So you would expect the helper class code (after the `await` has completed) to be run on the UI thread and not a b/g thread (which is what's happening to me)? I'm not using `Task.Run` anywhere. I also tried `ConfigureAwait(false)` btw, but it didn't help.

Comment: Yes, that's what I expect. Try making the code async all the way down, as I described. Get rid of blocking Result or Wait.

Comment: Thanks for giving me something to go on. Unfortunately in my real code the helper class is actually made up of a number of separate classes, with the second SignalR `invoke` down within nested methods. Making everything async may be a big ask without some refactoring! It's not the end of the world if Initialise() wasn't async - I was mostly curious as to what was causing the problem, in case it came back to bite later on when I really do need some async functionality.